# How to bind a C# DataSet with info from SQL Server query to a Telerik Radmap VisualizationLayer

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, telerik, spatial

I have a DataSet with information from a SQL Server query

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
,[Name]
,[placemark]
FROM [testmap].[dbo].[table1]
```

with the following result:

[Result query (click to see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvq5a.png)

SQL Management Studio also can show Spatial Results

[Vector geography](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISdzM.png)

I need to bind that map vector to a Telerik RadMap VisualizationLayer and show it above the plain satelite map. In their documentation shows a way to load it one by one with the latitude and longitude but I need to load it with the info in the database. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.